# WPF Animated GIF Use Too Much Memory for Displaying Large GIF Image

Tags: wpf, xaml, animated-gif

I want to display a GIF by using a library [WPF Animated GIF](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif). But when the property `PictureSource` is set, the process memory rises from **208MB** to **1GB**. Why?

[image]

### XAML

```
<Image Name="content" MaxHeight="240" MaxWidth="340" 
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"
       Width="340" Height="240"
       MinWidth="340" MinHeight="240"
       gif:ImageBehavior.AutoStart="True"
       gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding Path=PictureSource}">
        <Image.Stretch>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImageStretchConverter}">
                <Binding Path="PictureSource" />
                <Binding ElementName="content" Path="Source.Width" />
                <Binding ElementName="content" Path="Source.Height" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Stretch>
        <Image.BitmapEffect>
            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="0" />
        </Image.BitmapEffect>
    <Image.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache EnableClearType="True" 
                RenderAtScale="0.2" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
    </Image.CacheMode>
    <!--<Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage StreamSource="{Binding Path=PictureSource}" UriSource="{Binding Path=PictureSource}"
            DecodePixelWidth="340" DecodePixelHeight="240"/>
    </Image.Source>-->
</Image>
```

### ImageStretchConverter

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    string path = values[0] as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[2] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) {
        return Stretch.None;
    }

    if (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower() == ".gif") {
        double width = (double)values[1];
        double height = (double)values[2];
        if (width > Configuration.MaxThumbnailResolution || height > Configuration.MaxThumbnailResolution) {
            return Stretch.UniformToFill;
        }
    }

    return Stretch.None;
}
```

The size of the original GIF image is quite high. This may cause the problem. How can I set the `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` of the `AnimatedSource`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your ImageStretchConverter doing anything that can't be done with the Image's StretchDirection property? Besides that it's hardly relevant for your question.

Comment: So it seems you're setting UniformToFill when the Source is wider or taller than MaxThumbnailResolution. You could as well set the Image's MaxWidth and MaxHeight to this value, and then (always) set UniformToFill and StretchDirection to DownOnly.

Comment: The program always go to the line `return Stretch.None`. When I change it to `Stretch.UniformToFill`, it just resize the observable image but the memory usage is still very high.

Comment: Since the image should be GIF format, the converter method is being kept calling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you read this article on the problem? 
https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/01/17/a-new-library-to-display-animated-gifs-in-xaml-apps/

The problem is most likely caused by a mistake the developer made when creating the library.
You can read all about it in the article, but for a short explanation.

All the frames are pre-rendered in memory, for large gifs this is a big problem. Sadly enough there really isn't a easy fix for that when using the same library without re-programming it.

I'd recommend trying to use **XamlAnimatedGif**.

https://github.com/thomaslevesque/XamlAnimatedGif

(Which was made by the *Same Developer*)