# WPF Caliburn Micro memory issue using ActivateItem

Tags: c#, wpf, gif, caliburn.micro

I have a conductor `ShellViewModel` containing another conductor `SetupViewModel` which will be shown after a certain authentication process. The `SetupViewModel` has three Buttons and a ContentControl. Each Button shows one of three screens via `ActivateItem(xyzViewModel)`, where each ViewModel `x,y,z` is registered as Singleton in my `SimpleContainer`.

The problem I am facing is that screen `x` is showing a memory consuming GIF, which will be loaded from local storage. Every time I switch between the screens (= click one of the buttons), my application seems not only to show, but also reload the screen, up to the point where reloading screen `x` 3 times will crash the application, as it uses over 4GB of process memory, while loading the data from the local storage is only done once.

1. Was I wrong to assume that `ActivateItem(...)` would activate the View binded to a ViewModel, sort of like `Show()` in WinForms? I am not closing the ViewModel via `TryClose()` when switching, so I assumed it will be open, just not visible.
2. Is there any way to implement the needed functionality without destroying the MVVM pattern via an ugly workaround?

I really don't know if I'm missing out on something, this issue is really stalling my development process.

My Code in the `SetupViewModel`:

```
private readonly SettingsViewModel _settingsVM;

public SetupViewModel(IEventAggregator events, SettingsViewModel settingsVM)
{
     _events = events;
     _events.Subscribe(this);
     _settingsVM = settingsVM;
}

public void Settings()
{
    ActivateItem(_settingsVM);
}
```

Whereas my `SettingsViewModel`:

```
private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
bool loaded;
public SettingsViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
      _events = events;
}
//Triggered everytime I call ActivateItem(_settingsVM), so I try to load data only once
protected override async void OnViewLoaded(object view)  
{
     base.OnViewLoaded(view);
     if (!loaded)
     {
          await LoadSettings();
          loaded = true;
     }
}
```

EDIT: Many thanks to @Eldar. As @Eldar pointed out, I mentioned the use of GIF Image. Here is a rough Code representation of my `SettingsView`:

```
<UserControl
:
:
xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com">

            <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding LogoPath}"
                Stretch="Uniform"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />

</UserControl>
```

The real issue was indeed [WpfAnimatedGif](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif). The developer created a new package [XamlAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif), as the old library "used an awful lot of memory". Using the new library fixed the problem.

Comment: You should register your `SettingsViewModel` as singleton.

Comment: Assume `x` is `SettingsViewModel`

Comment: Sorry i fail to read that part. As i noticed you are showing GIF images in your form. Can you share it please. Image manipulation could be the reason of leaking memory.

Comment: Hello @Eldar, i added the Code snippets to the question

Comment: As it seems the library you use causing this kind of memory usage. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768644/wpf-animated-gif-use-too-much-memory-for-displaying-large-gif-image) and the other [libray](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/XamlAnimatedGif)

Comment: Thank you very much, never expected it to be this library! You saved my sunday :D

Comment: Not directly connected to the question in hand, but if someone's wondering, Caliburn 'ActivateItem' shifted to 'ActivateItemAsync'.

Comment: @DamnjanMarkovic yeah they made a lot of stuff async, and included CancellationTokens